# Cannot start Neo4j - getting unable to bind to port

Tags: neo4j

I am using mac os, every time I am trying to start Neo4j I am getting this error

> Unable to bind to port. Are you running another Neo4j process on this
>   computer?

tried to check the default port

> lsof -i :5001

but nothing is bind to that port

same result checking the activity monitor shows that neo4j not running

Comment: ios? are you sure?

Comment: @stdob-- yes I am ...

Comment: `ios` would imply you're running a Neo4j server on an iPhone/ipad, and there is no Neo4j installation targeting ios. Perhaps you should edit your question to further explain? This doesn't make much sense.

Comment: sorry I meant OS I will correct that

Comment: @stdob-- Note that neo4j can run on iOS : https://github.com/GraphStory/neo4j-ios

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen I think it is only an interface for interact with remote Neo4j.

Comment: Mmh yeah you're right. Sad :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is 5001 your browser port ?

I would check if there is usage on the following :

---

**Old Neo4j Versions ( < 3.0 )**

Port 7474 (neo4j browser) :  `lsof -i -n -P | grep 7474`

Port 1337 (neo4j-shell): `lsof -i -n -P | grep 1337`

---

**Neo4j > 3.x**

Port 7474 (neo4j browser) :  `lsof -i -n -P | grep 7474`

Port 7687 (neo4j bolt) :  `lsof -i -n -P | grep 7687`

---

Same for 7473

For the shell, for example Tunnelbclick is using 1337 and sometimes conflicts with neo4j.

If it doesn't work, try to kill your java processes :

`sudo killall -9 java`