# Unable to bind to port. Are you running another Neo4j process on this computer?

Tags: macos, neo4j, port

I am trying to start the neo4j on mac,but all the time ,it represent the results 'Unable to bind to port. Are you running another Neo4j process on this computer?'.after this ,I have tried to shut down the java process, but it didn't work .so I want to ask help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot start Neo4j - getting unable to bind to port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37483303/cannot-start-neo4j-getting-unable-to-bind-to-port)

Answer (score 0):

You have another process running, which blocks the port. Most often, it happens when you open the Neo4j application, start the server with the GUI, and then try to start a Neo4j instance from your IDE. A restart should clear this problem, or search for open processes that use that port.